# Asp.Net MVC best way to update cached table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, t-sql, design-patterns

There are certain tables that get called often but updated rarely. One of these tables is Departments. So to save DB trips, I think it is ok to cache this table taking into consideration that the table has very small size. However, once you cached it an issue of keeping the table data fresh occurs. So what is the best way to determine that the table is dirty and therefore requires a reload and how that code should be invoked. I look for solution that will be scalable. So updating the cache on single right after inserting will not resolve the issue. If one machine inserted the record all other on the farm should get notified to reload the cache. I was thinking for calling corresponding web service from T-SQL  but don't really like the idea of consuming recourses on sql server. So what are the best practices to resolve this type of problems. 
Thanks in advance
Eddy

Comment: Can you give more information about your architecture. Do you have a data layer? Ar you already caching?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using sql dependencies or cache dependencies? The library will pole the database every so often to see if the data has changed. An alternative is to use cache dependencies too. You can have a master cache object and have child caches depend on it. so if the master cache change the child caches will be updated.

**Edit:**
If the above is not a solution you can easily use [memcached.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/memcacheddotnet/) -- [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached). Geared toward large sites but it is a solution for your problem.

Comment: This will work only on machine that inserted the record but all other machines on the farm will be unnotified so their data will not be refreshed.

Comment: I have editied my answer. I think memcached will solve your problem. Also, it is open source and free

Answer (score 0):

There are some great distributed caching frameworks out there. Have a look at NCache and Velocity. NCache has some great features for keeping the cached data in sync between different cache nodes as well as the underlying database. But it comes at a price.

Comment: I know about them but they are expensive and more applicable for large scale applications besides it does not really show how to resolve such type of problems except using their tool. But thank you for the post

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that describes the thinking around setting up a cache.

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2001/jw-0720-cache.html?page=1

Generally speaking objects in a cache have lifetimes and when the lifetime expires they are re-fetched from the database. If the data is not so important this eventual consistency allows for a mixture of performance and accuracy of presented information.

Other cache tools add in additional techniques to keep data more accurate i.e. if a particular object is known to be updated then repopulate after the update command is executed.